# non-linear first ODE with boundary condition

Tags: differential-equations

I'm looking for analytical solution for this equation:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
eqn = {(y'[t]^2/y[t]^2) - b (y'[t]/y[t]) - k/(3*y[t]^2) - f/3 == 0};
DSolve[{eqn, y[0] == 1}, y[t], t]
```

Comment: Looking at `DSolve[{(y'[t]^2/y[t]^2) - b (y'[t]/y[t]) - k/(3*y[t]^2) - f/3 == 0}, y, t]`, it doesn't look like it'll be easy for you to get a simple, explicit solution.

Comment: The problem is in resolving the initial conditions. Since you have undefined parameters, Mathematica is having hard time deciding when it tries to solve for the constant of integration. It can solve it without IC. It also can solve it with same IC, but with specific values given to `b,k,f`. The solution contains inverse functions which what makes it hard to solve for the constant of integration.  Btw, Maple can not solve it either with the IC in there. So the problem is really a `Solve` problem and not a `DSolve` problem.

Comment: It is possible your initial conditions are wrong to obtain a possible solution.

Comment: It's a separable equation, so it's relatively straightforward to get a solution in the form of an implicit equation (with `Log` & `ArcTan` of course).

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes. I already did that. I did not post it because I could not verify the initial conditions. I posted below what I have and may be you have a look. I could only verify the ODE itself, but not the IC. No time to spend more on it to find why.

Comment: @Nasser I suppose you just need that there are no singularities between `1` and `y[t]` -- but that could be the difficulty with so many symbolic parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my hand solution with the help of the computer

Solve
\begin{gather*}
\boxed{\frac{\left(y^{\prime}\right)^{2}}{y^{2}}-\frac{b y^{\prime}}{y}-\frac{k}{3 y^{2}}-\frac{f}{3}=0}
\end{gather*}
With initial conditions
$$
y \left(0\right) = 1
$$

Solving for $y^{\prime}$ gives
\begin{align*}
   y^{\prime}&=\frac{y b}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{9 y^{2} b^{2}+12 f y^{2}+12 k}}{6}\tag{1} \\ 
y^{\prime}&=\frac{y b}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{9 y^{2} b^{2}+12 f y^{2}+12 k}}{6}\tag{2} 
\end{align*}
Now ODE (1) is solved (ODE 2 will not be solved here, as same method applies to it)

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\frac{y b}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{\left(9 b^{2}+12 f \right) y^{2}+12 k}}{6}}\mathop{\mathrm{d}y}&= \mathop{\mathrm{d}t}\\   
\int \frac{1}{\frac{y b}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{\left(9 b^{2}+12 f \right) y^{2}+12 k}}{6}}\mathop{\mathrm{d}y}&= \int \mathop{\mathrm{d}t}
\end{align*}
Which gives

\begin{align*}
\frac{\sqrt{\left(9 b^{2}+12 f \right) \left(y -\frac{\sqrt{-f k}}{f}\right)^{2}+\frac{6 \left(3 b^{2}+4 f \right) \sqrt{-f k}\, \left(y -\frac{\sqrt{-f k}}{f}\right)}{f}-\frac{9 k \,b^{2}}{f}}}{4 \sqrt{-f k}}+\frac{9 \ln \left(\frac{\frac{3 \left(3 b^{2}+4 f \right) \sqrt{-f k}}{f}+\left(9 b^{2}+12 f \right) \left(y -\frac{\sqrt{-f k}}{f}\right)}{\sqrt{9 b^{2}+12 f}}+\sqrt{\left(9 b^{2}+12 f \right) \left(y -\frac{\sqrt{-f k}}{f}\right)^{2}+\frac{6 \left(3 b^{2}+4 f \right) \sqrt{-f k}\, \left(y -\frac{\sqrt{-f k}}{f}\right)}{f}-\frac{9 k \,b^{2}}{f}}\right) b^{2}}{4 f \sqrt{9 b^{2}+12 f}}+\frac{3 \ln \left(\frac{\frac{3 \left(3 b^{2}+4 f \right) \sqrt{-f k}}{f}+\left(9 b^{2}+12 f \right) \left(y -\frac{\sqrt{-f k}}{f}\right)}{\sqrt{9 b^{2}+12 f}}+\sqrt{\left(9 b^{2}+12 f \right) \left(y -\frac{\sqrt{-f k}}{f}\right)^{2}+\frac{6 \left(3 b^{2}+4 f \right) \sqrt{-f k}\, \left(y -\frac{\sqrt{-f k}}{f}\right)}{f}-\frac{9 k \,b^{2}}{f}}\right)}{\sqrt{9 b^{2}+12 f}}+\frac{3 k \,b^{2} \ln \left(\frac{-\frac{18 k \,b^{2}}{f}+\frac{6 \left(3 b^{2}+4 f \right) \sqrt{-f k}\, \left(y -\frac{\sqrt{-f k}}{f}\right)}{f}+6 \sqrt{-\frac{k \,b^{2}}{f}}\, \sqrt{\left(9 b^{2}+12 f \right) \left(y -\frac{\sqrt{-f k}}{f}\right)^{2}+\frac{6 \left(3 b^{2}+4 f \right) \sqrt{-f k}\, \left(y -\frac{\sqrt{-f k}}{f}\right)}{f}-\frac{9 k \,b^{2}}{f}}}{y -\frac{\sqrt{-f k}}{f}}\right)}{4 \sqrt{-f k}\, f \sqrt{-\frac{k \,b^{2}}{f}}}-\frac{\sqrt{\left(9 b^{2}+12 f \right) \left(y +\frac{\sqrt{-f k}}{f}\right)^{2}-\frac{6 \left(3 b^{2}+4 f \right) \sqrt{-f k}\, \left(y +\frac{\sqrt{-f k}}{f}\right)}{f}-\frac{9 k \,b^{2}}{f}}}{4 \sqrt{-f k}}+\frac{9 \ln \left(\frac{-\frac{3 \left(3 b^{2}+4 f \right) \sqrt{-f k}}{f}+\left(9 b^{2}+12 f \right) \left(y +\frac{\sqrt{-f k}}{f}\right)}{\sqrt{9 b^{2}+12 f}}+\sqrt{\left(9 b^{2}+12 f \right) \left(y +\frac{\sqrt{-f k}}{f}\right)^{2}-\frac{6 \left(3 b^{2}+4 f \right) \sqrt{-f k}\, \left(y +\frac{\sqrt{-f k}}{f}\right)}{f}-\frac{9 k \,b^{2}}{f}}\right) b^{2}}{4 f \sqrt{9 b^{2}+12 f}}+\frac{3 \ln \left(\frac{-\frac{3 \left(3 b^{2}+4 f \right) \sqrt{-f k}}{f}+\left(9 b^{2}+12 f \right) \left(y +\frac{\sqrt{-f k}}{f}\right)}{\sqrt{9 b^{2}+12 f}}+\sqrt{\left(9 b^{2}+12 f \right) \left(y +\frac{\sqrt{-f k}}{f}\right)^{2}-\frac{6 \left(3 b^{2}+4 f \right) \sqrt{-f k}\, \left(y +\frac{\sqrt{-f k}}{f}\right)}{f}-\frac{9 k \,b^{2}}{f}}\right)}{\sqrt{9 b^{2}+12 f}}-\frac{3 k \,b^{2} \ln \left(\frac{-\frac{18 k \,b^{2}}{f}-\frac{6 \left(3 b^{2}+4 f \right) \sqrt{-f k}\, \left(y +\frac{\sqrt{-f k}}{f}\right)}{f}+6 \sqrt{-\frac{k \,b^{2}}{f}}\, \sqrt{\left(9 b^{2}+12 f \right) \left(y +\frac{\sqrt{-f k}}{f}\right)^{2}-\frac{6 \left(3 b^{2}+4 f \right) \sqrt{-f k}\, \left(y +\frac{\sqrt{-f k}}{f}\right)}{f}-\frac{9 k \,b^{2}}{f}}}{y +\frac{\sqrt{-f k}}{f}}\right)}{4 \sqrt{-f k}\, f \sqrt{-\frac{k \,b^{2}}{f}}}-\frac{3 b \ln \left(f \,y^{2}+k \right)}{4 f} = t +c_{1}
\end{align*}

Initial conditions are used to solve for $c_{1}$.

Substituting $t=0$ and $y=1$ in the above solution gives an equation to solve for the constant of integration.
\begin{align*}
c_{1} = -\frac{3 \left(6 \ln \left(\frac{\sqrt{9 b^{2}+12 f +12 k}\, \sqrt{9 b^{2}+12 f}+9 b^{2}+12 f}{\sqrt{9 b^{2}+12 f}}\right) b^{2} \sqrt{-f k}\, \sqrt{-\frac{k \,b^{2}}{f}}+b \ln \left(f +k \right) \sqrt{9 b^{2}+12 f}\, \sqrt{-f k}\, \sqrt{-\frac{k \,b^{2}}{f}}+k \,b^{2} \sqrt{9 b^{2}+12 f}\, \ln \left(\frac{\sqrt{-\frac{k \,b^{2}}{f}}\, \sqrt{9 b^{2}+12 f +12 k}\, f +\left(3 b^{2}+4 f \right) \sqrt{-f k}+4 f k}{f -\sqrt{-f k}}\right)-k \,b^{2} \sqrt{9 b^{2}+12 f}\, \ln \left(\frac{\sqrt{-\frac{k \,b^{2}}{f}}\, \sqrt{9 b^{2}+12 f +12 k}\, f +\left(-3 b^{2}-4 f \right) \sqrt{-f k}+4 f k}{f +\sqrt{-f k}}\right)+8 \ln \left(\frac{\sqrt{9 b^{2}+12 f +12 k}\, \sqrt{9 b^{2}+12 f}+9 b^{2}+12 f}{\sqrt{9 b^{2}+12 f}}\right) f \sqrt{-f k}\, \sqrt{-\frac{k \,b^{2}}{f}}\right)}{4 f \sqrt{9 b^{2}+12 f}\, \sqrt{-f k}\, \sqrt{-\frac{k \,b^{2}}{f}}}
\end{align*}
Substituting $c_{1}$ found above in the general solution gives after simplification the implicit solution

$$
\frac{9 \left(\left(b^{2}+\frac{4 f}{3}\right) \ln \left(\sqrt{\left(9 b^{2}+12 f \right) y^{2}+12 k}+\sqrt{9 b^{2}+12 f}\, y\right)-\frac{b \ln \left(f y^{2}+k \right) \sqrt{9 b^{2}+12 f}}{6}\right) \sqrt{-\frac{k \,b^{2}}{f}}\, \sqrt{-f k}}{2}+\frac{3 k \,b^{2} \left(\ln \left(\frac{\sqrt{-\frac{k \,b^{2}}{f}}\, \sqrt{\left(9 b^{2}+12 f \right) y^{2}+12 k}\, f +3 \sqrt{-f k}\, \left(b^{2}+\frac{4 f}{3}\right) y+4 f k}{f y-\sqrt{-f k}}\right)-\ln \left(\frac{\sqrt{-\frac{k \,b^{2}}{f}}\, \sqrt{\left(9 b^{2}+12 f \right) y^{2}+12 k}\, f -3 \sqrt{-f k}\, \left(b^{2}+\frac{4 f}{3}\right) y+4 f k}{f y+\sqrt{-f k}}\right)\right) \sqrt{9 b^{2}+12 f}}{4} = \frac{9 \left(\sqrt{9 b^{2}+12 f}\, \left(-\frac{b \ln \left(f +k \right)}{6}+\frac{2 f t}{9}\right)+\frac{\left(3 b^{2}+4 f \right) \ln \left(\frac{\sqrt{9 b^{2}+12 f +12 k}\, \sqrt{9 b^{2}+12 f}+9 b^{2}+12 f}{\sqrt{9 b^{2}+12 f}}\right)}{3}\right) \sqrt{-f k}\, \sqrt{-\frac{k \,b^{2}}{f}}}{2}-\frac{3 \sqrt{9 b^{2}+12 f}\, k \,b^{2} \left(-\ln \left(\frac{\sqrt{-\frac{k \,b^{2}}{f}}\, \sqrt{9 b^{2}+12 f +12 k}\, f +\left(3 b^{2}+4 f \right) \sqrt{-f k}+4 f k}{f -\sqrt{-f k}}\right)+\ln \left(\frac{\sqrt{-\frac{k \,b^{2}}{f}}\, \sqrt{9 b^{2}+12 f +12 k}\, f +\left(-3 b^{2}-4 f \right) \sqrt{-f k}+4 f k}{f +\sqrt{-f k}}\right)\right)}{4}
$$

In Mathematica code, the solution is (note, it is implicit solution, can not solve for $y(t)$).

```
(9*Sqrt[-((b^2*k)/f)]*Sqrt[-(f*k)]*(-1/6*(b*Sqrt[9*b^2 + 12*f]*Log[k + f*y[t]^2]) + (b^2 + (4*f)/3)*Log[Sqrt[9*b^2 + 12*f]*y[t] + Sqrt[12*k + (9*b^2 + 12*f)*y[t]^2]]))/2 + 
  (3*b^2*Sqrt[9*b^2 + 12*f]*k*(-Log[(4*f*k - 3*(b^2 + (4*f)/3)*Sqrt[-(f*k)]*t*y[t] + f*Sqrt[-((b^2*k)/f)]*Sqrt[12*k + (9*b^2 + 12*f)*y[t]^2])/(Sqrt[-(f*k)] + f*y[t])] + 
     Log[(4*f*k + 3*(b^2 + (4*f)/3)*Sqrt[-(f*k)]*t*y[t] + f*Sqrt[-((b^2*k)/f)]*Sqrt[12*k + (9*b^2 + 12*f)*y[t]^2])/(-Sqrt[-(f*k)] + f*y[t])]))/4 == 
 (9*Sqrt[-((b^2*k)/f)]*Sqrt[-(f*k)]*(Sqrt[9*b^2 + 12*f]*((2*f*t)/9 - (b*Log[f + k])/6) + ((3*b^2 + 4*f)*Log[(9*b^2 + 12*f + Sqrt[9*b^2 + 12*f]*Sqrt[9*b^2 + 12*f + 12*k])/Sqrt[9*b^2 + 12*f]])/3))/2 - 
  (3*b^2*Sqrt[9*b^2 + 12*f]*k*(Log[(4*f*k + (-3*b^2 - 4*f)*Sqrt[-(f*k)] + f*Sqrt[-((b^2*k)/f)]*Sqrt[9*b^2 + 12*f + 12*k])/(f + Sqrt[-(f*k)])] - 
     Log[(4*f*k + (3*b^2 + 4*f)*Sqrt[-(f*k)] + f*Sqrt[-((b^2*k)/f)]*Sqrt[9*b^2 + 12*f + 12*k])/(f - Sqrt[-(f*k)])]))/4
```

in Traditional form the solution is

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The above was verified correct on the ODE. But could not use Mathematica or Maple to verify the solution on the initial conditions.

Comment: A shorter way to express the solution is $$\int_1^y {dy \over y'} = \int_0^t dt$$ Then you do not need to solve for the IC. But it's basically the same thing as you did. Verifying Mma's algebra/calculus is still difficult.

Comment: @MichaelE2 thanks for spotting it. Fixed. I did some manual conversion.

Comment: with y'[0]==1 can make it more simple??

Comment: *with y'[0]==1 can make it more simple??* hi Armin. You can  not use such initial condition. This is first order ODE. Hence the initial condition can't have order same as the order of the ode or higher. This means only $y(x_0)=y_0$ is possible

Comment: @ArminSharafi  [Sorry, typo in original comment.] `y'[0] == 1` is equivalent to the two initial conditions given by `Solve[eqn /. t -> 0 /. y'[0] -> 1, y[0]]`. You can try them. I doubt setting `y[0]` or `y'[0]` to a specific number will help given that eqn has so many constant parameters. Your choosing different conditions makes me wonder why you are interested in this particular solution or that one? Are just trying to find any solution just so long as it's simple? Why aren't the conditions more important than the simplicity?

Answer (score 2):

This is the same idea as Nasser's, but my route yielded solutions in a slightly different form.

```
Solve[eqn, y'[t]];
Inactive[Integrate][1/y'[t], y[t]] /. % // 
    Activate // # - (# /. y[t] -> 1) & // FullSimplify;
sols = Thread[% == t];

sols /. y[t] -> 1 // Simplify  (* Check IC *)

(*  {t == 0, t == 0}  *)

Solve[#, y'[t]] & /@ D[sols, t] // Apply@Join;
eqn /. % // FullSimplify       (* Check ODE *)

(*  {{True}, {True}}  *)
```

Here's the first solution:

$$\frac{b f \left(2 \left(\sqrt{b^2 f}+b f\right) \log
   \left(\sqrt{b^2 f y(t)^2+k}-\sqrt{b^2 f}
   y(t)\right)-\sqrt{b^2 f} \log \left(f \left(b^2
   (f-1) y(t)^2+k\right) \left(-2 \sqrt{b^2 f} y(t)
   \sqrt{b^2 f y(t)^2+k}+2 b^2 f
   y(t)^2+k\right)\right)+2 b \sqrt{f} \coth
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{f} k}{(f-1) y(t) \left(b^2
   f y(t)-\sqrt{b^2 f} \sqrt{b^2 f
   y(t)^2+k}\right)+f k}\right)-2 \left(\sqrt{b^2
   f}+b f\right) \log \left(\sqrt{b^2 f+k}-\sqrt{b^2
   f}\right)+\sqrt{b^2 f} \log \left(f \left(b^2
   (f-1)+k\right) \left(-2 \sqrt{b^2 f} \sqrt{b^2
   f+k}+2 b^2 f+k\right)\right)-2 b \sqrt{f} \coth
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{f} k}{-(f-1) \sqrt{b^2 f}
   \sqrt{b^2 f+k}+b^2 (f-1) f+f
   k}\right)\right)}{(f-1) \left(b^2
   f\right)^{3/2}}=t$$